# PyQt multiple buttons print same value

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm having three buttons on a form, what I expect for example is when I click the 5% button it prints 5%. But for some reason for all buttons it print's 60%.

And I really don't understand why?

My code is below.

```
class ThirdWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form3):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThirdWindow, self).__init__()
        self.dbu = DatabaseHandling.DatabaseUtility()
        self.msl = None

        # Show UI on screen + resize window
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.picIndicator.setPixmap(QPixmap("M:\QtProjects\\Resources\\138691.png"))
        self.setFixedSize(350, 480)

        #  Define what should happen on button click
        self.btnQuit.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())
        self.btnSixtyPercent.clicked.connect(lambda: self.check_clicked())
        self.btnTenPercent.clicked.connect(lambda: self.check_clicked())
        self.btnFivePercent.clicked.connect(lambda: self.check_clicked())


    #  TODO: Create a window that ask's for the spot it's specific color
    '''def indication(self):
        d = DialogOne()
        d.exec_()'''

    def check_clicked(self):
        if self.btnSixtyPercent.text() == "60":
            print("60%")
        elif self.btnFivePercent.text() == "5":
            print("5%")
        elif self.btnTenPercent.text() == "10":
            print("10%")
```

[image: Form]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect the signals to the slot, it executes when the signal is generated, if you want to work with the object that emits the signal you can use the `sender()`.It is not necessary to use `lambda` functions.

```
    self.btnQuit.clicked.connect(self.close)
    self.btnSixtyPercent.clicked.connect(self.check_clicked)
    self.btnTenPercent.clicked.connect(self.check_clicked)
    self.btnFivePercent.clicked.connect(self.check_clicked)


def check_clicked(self):
        print("{}%".format(self.sender().text()
```

Complete code:

```
class ThirdWindow(QWidget, Ui_Form3):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ThirdWindow, self).__init__()
        self.dbu = DatabaseHandling.DatabaseUtility()
        self.msl = None

        # Show UI on screen + resize window
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.picIndicator.setPixmap(QPixmap("M:\QtProjects\\Resources\\138691.png"))
        self.setFixedSize(350, 480)

        #  Define what should happen on button click
        self.btnQuit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.btnSixtyPercent.clicked.connect(self.check_clicked)
        self.btnTenPercent.clicked.connect(self.check_clicked)
        self.btnFivePercent.clicked.connect(self.check_clicked)


    #  TODO: Create a window that ask's for the spot it's specific color
    '''def indication(self):
        d = DialogOne()
        d.exec_()'''

    def check_clicked(self):
        print("{}%".format(self.sender().text()))
```

Comment: is the following possible?: If I remove the button text, and want to check which button is pressed using isChecked can you show me a quick example of that?

Comment: Of course it is possible since in `sender()` you will have the object, in that case the `QCheckBox`, and you can use its functions.  On the other hand I think that my answer answered your doubt, if so I did it please mark it as correct.

Comment: For this case we must use the signal stateChanged, that can give us information of the button.

Comment: Can you add an example using my code? I would appreciate that a lot! :)

Comment: btnSixtyPercent, btnTenPercent, btnFivePercent are QCheckBoxs?

Comment: They are QPushButtons, the round shaped circles on my image in the first post represent the buttons.

Comment: `isChecked()` is an attribute that is used synchronously, this is unnecessary, the signals are executed asynchronously and in your case clicked will only be executed if the button is checked. `sender()` returns the object that was emitted when it was clicked

Comment: By example: `def check_clicked(self):
        if self.sender() == self.btnSixtyPercent:
            print("self.btnSixtyPercent")
        elif self.sender() == self.btnTenPercent:
            print("self.btnTenPercent")
        elif self.sender() == self.btnFivePercent:
            print("self.btnFivePercent")`

Comment: This works thanks, but I'm having trouble again when I want to pass this to another class which inherits from QDialog.

Comment: I think that already helps you enough, you must read about object oriented programming so you can solve your problems